# React Native Phone Number Input

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I've been hunting the web trying to find out how to get the standard IOS number input fields to be displayed through React Native but am having no luck. I've found libraries like [React-Native-Phone-Input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-input) however don't want the bulk of another library.

All I need is the ability to display the native number input field, that is if this is even possible?

[image: IOS Text Input]

Comment: use `keyboardType={'phone-pad'} or keyboardType={'number-pad'} ` in `TextInput`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Refer the below react native component property

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#keyboardtype

Use the

```
<TextInput keyboardType={'phone-pad'} />
```